# Git checkout - prefer branch over tag

Tags: git

Suppose there is a tag and a branch with identical names.

Doing `git checkout foo` prefers to check out the tag, and leaves the repo in a detached head state.

How do I tel git that I want to check out the branch not the tag?

An advice I found here https://groups.google.com/g/git-users/c/FfzGmqj6sNQ is to use `git checkout refs/heads/foo` but for me this gives an error: "pathspec did not match any files(s) known to git".

Here are my refs:

```
some_hash1 refs/remotes/origin/foo
some_hash2 refs/tags/foo
```

As you can see there is no `refs/heads/foo`.

Tried "git switch refs/remotes/origin/foo" and this errors out too: "fatal: a branch is expected, got remote branch".

I'm running git 2.40.0

The branch "foo" is there in GitHub web UI.

Comment: you need a local branch `foo` tracking `origin/foo` to be able to checkout to it

Comment: `git checkout` does not prefer tags over branches. If a tag and a local branch with the same name exists, it displays a warning telling that the name is ambiguous and checks out the branch. In your case it checks out the tag because a local branch with that name does not exist. You can run `git checkout foo` and it creates the local branch `foo` that tracks the remote branch `foo` then checks out the newly created remote branch but this is just a courtesy for the developers and happens when a local reference named `foo` does not exist and a remote branch `foo` exists.

Comment: >> If a tag and a local branch with the same name exists, it displays a warning telling that the name is ambiguous and checks out the branch << Only if there already is a local branch for that name. If there isn't, it will check out the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Found answer here:

https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/track-remote-upstream-branch

```
git checkout --track origin/foo
```

After this `git show-ref` shows the local branch `foo` under `refs/heads`:

```
$ git show-ref | grep foo
some_hash1 refs/heads/foo
some_hash1 refs/remotes/origin/foo
some_hash2 refs/tags/foo
```